# Почему в возвращаемом типе используется typename и не используется decltype?

Tags: c++

Известно, что `std::result_of` нужен для определения типа возвращаемого значения вызова функции. И аналогично работает его обновленная версия из C++17 - `invoke_result`

```
#define _SILENCE_CXX17_RESULT_OF_DEPRECATION_WARNING
#include <type_traits>

int fn(int) 
{ 
     return int();
}  

int main() 
{
     std::result_of<decltype(&fn)(int)>::type y; // y - это int
     y = 5;


     std::invoke_result<decltype(&fn),int>::type k;
     k = 6;

     return 0;

}
```

Почему в [этом ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21941687/8313610), используется typename,если тип явно указывается с помощью std::result_of<F(void)>?

```
template<typename F>                            
std::future<typename std::result_of<F()>::type> 
runCmd(const std::string& cmd, F callback)
{
 ...
```

Второй вопрос: в функцию `runCmd` передаётся лямбда и её тип описывается шаблонным типом F, то есть тип уже известен и узнавать его через decltype не нужно, верно?

---

Дополняя пример из указанного вопроса, код с `decltype` получается таким:

```
#include <thread>
#include <future>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

void system()
{
     std::cout << "Executing system with argument '" << "ls" << "'\n";
}



template<class F>
auto runCmd(F callback) -> std::future<decltype(callback())>
{
     auto fut = std::async(std::launch::async, [callback] { system(); return callback(); });
     return fut;
}


int main()
{
     auto fut = runCmd([] { std::cout << "Executing callback\n"; });
     fut.get();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`typename` нужен только в шаблонах, перед конструкциями вида `... T ... :: ...`, где `T` - шаблонный параметр, или что-то, что от него зависит.

Чтобы компилятор мог не глядя на `T` определить, что там после `::`, тип или что-то другок, например переменная.

В С++20, в случаях где это и так понятно, `typename` можно не писать.

---

> её тип описывается шаблонным типом F, то есть тип уже известен и узнавать его через decltype не нужно

Если использовать `F`, то да. Но можно сделать `decltype(f(аргументы))`.

Comment: 'std::future<typename std::result_of<decltype(callback(void))>::type> runCmd(F callback)'

не работает((

Comment: @Elvin Вы используете `result_of` неправильно (и непонятно, зачем вообще его используете, если его выкинули из стандарта - уж либо `std::invoke_result_t`, либо просто `decltype`). `callback` нельзя использовать до списка параметров, в котором он описан - либо записывать через `F`, либо писать возвращаемый тип справа от параметров ([trailing return type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function)). `callback(void)` - бессмыслица (вы же не пишете `std::sin(double)`), можно `decltype(callback())` (тогда вообще `result_of` не нужон).

Comment: Если не поможет, сделайте пример на https://gcc.godbolt.org

Comment: template<class F>
auto runCmd(F callback) -> std::future<decltype(callback())>
{
     auto fut = std::async(std::launch::async,[callback] { system(); return callback(); });
     return fut;
}
Типа такого?

Comment: @Elvin На первый взглядит выглядит нормально. Работает?

Comment: да, я хотел использовать именно decltype и имя функции. То есть 'decltype(f(аргументы))' сработает, если использовать trailing return type. В остальных случаях нужно использовать  result_of/invoke_result , верно?

Comment: @Elvin Логика немного задом наперед. Выбор между trailing return type и не-trailing - он чисто про удобство записи, и не должен влиять на поведение вашей программы. А `invoke_result` ведет себя не совсем так, как `decltype(f(...))` (`result_of` вообще не рассматриваю, раз его выкинули из стандарта). Чтобы переписать на не-trailing-return-type с полным сохранением поведения, используйте `std::declval()`.

Comment: А смысл использовать вещи с `...invoke...` в названии в том, чтобы поддержать вызов всяких необычных вещей как функций (указатели на члены) - но тогда это нужно делать везде (т.е. если написали `invoke_result` в возвращаемом типе, то и тело функции должно использовать `std::invoke` вместо обычного вызова функции).